# Updating to v2 date-fns: NaN

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, date-fns

I'm updating the module `date-fns` from v1 to v2.

This helper method used to work:

```
const { format, parseISO, differenceInSeconds } = require("date-fns");

const newDateNow = () => {
    const date = new Date();
    return format(date, process.env.DATE_FORMAT);
};

// `process.env.DATE_FORMAT` is set to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`
console.log(ff) //prints: Thu Jul 21 2022 14:44:56 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
console.log(gg) //prints: 3600
console.log(newDateNow()) //prints: 2022-07-21 15:32:05

const isExpired = () => {
    const exp = differenceInSeconds(newDateNow(), ff);
    return parseInt(gg) > exp;
}
```

After the update to the module's v2 this generates the error: `date-fns doesn't accept strings as date arguments. Please use 'parseISO' to parse strings.` This pointing to the `const exp` line.

So I change that line to:

```
const exp = differenceInSeconds(newDateNow(), parseISO(ff));
```

This still generates the same error, so I change it to:

```
const exp = differenceInSeconds(parseISO(newDateNow()), parseISO(ff));
```

Now there is no error, but `console.log(exp)` prints `NaN`.

How should I implement this? Shouldn't I change the `newDateNow` method so that it's not necessary to use `parseISO()` on `newDateNow()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`differenceInSeconds()` is a function which takes two `Date` objects as arguments. In your code, `newDateNow()` is returning a string because you’re calling `format()` on the date, so you’re passing it a string rather than a date.

So based on just needing to compare the two dates you should skip that call to `format()` entirely.

Your code sample doesn’t include the assignment of `ff`, you will need to ensure that is a date and not a string as well.

If you haven't seen already, the documentation is handy: https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/Getting-Started

Comment: Thanks @Peter, I've updated the OP after some more debugging.